# Phrase Usage:- "Works like a Charm", can it be used formally?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, formality, email

I have seen many people using the phrase "It works like a charm"....when they are asked about , how something is working/going on. Is it a correct way to use it in business communication.

For Example:- Q: "Is your application working(software)"?
              A: "Yes, ***it works like a charm"?***

Kindly throw some light on its usage. Can I use it in email to business clients or in a IM chat?

Comment: It's informal, but yes, it would appropriate for relatively informal business communication, in my opinion as a speaker of US English.

Answer (score 8):

**Works like a charm** is an idiom meaning something **that beings good luck or success** and **seems to have magical powers**

**Charms** are trinkets which people have for **good luck**. Examples are **rabbit's foot** and **horse shoes**.

The expression is **informal**, but very effective **expressively**.

A formal business equivalent would be

> The new product is **very effective**
>   The software is **very efficient**
>   The product **enables** us to do things not possible before

**Works like a charm** is equivalent to **works like a dream**. Both are **colloquial positive praises** for something